# The plugin `flutter_contact` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding

Tags: flutter

We are using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_contact/versions/0.9.1+7, is there a way to work around the following error

```
The plugin `flutter_contact` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.

To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.

If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
```

Comment: You should first update the library version and if there's any "issue" with a library, you have their GitHub "issue" section to post that. SoF considers off topic these type of questions

Answer (score 0):

This flutter_contact vesion is high version,so you use down vesion or you update your project to latest version.